# Android AccountManager - limit access to getAuthToken

Tags: android, android-permissions, accountmanager

`AccountManager` allows apps with the same signature as your `Account Authenticator` to access Accounts and tokens without granting permissions. If the signature differs, the system will prompt the User to grant the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission to the app.

What if you don't want to allow this? Is it possible to limit access to only your apps?

I was hopeful when I read the following, but I am not sure what they mean by this statement **or** how you would implement the suggestion:

> If credentials are to be used only by applications that you create, then you can verify the application which accesses the AccountManager using checkSignature()

https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html#Security

Answer (score 0):

Original answer here: [AccountManager and signature check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47334432/accountmanager-and-signature-check/47349745#47349745)

In short:

```
public Bundle getAuthToken(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account,
                       String authTokenType, Bundle bundle) {
try {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    String callerPackageName = bundle.getString("androidPackageName");
    // Caller app must be signed with the same key to get the auth token
    int signatureResult = packageManager.checkSignatures(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID,
            callerPackageName);
    if (signatureResult >= PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH) {
        return [bundle with the auth token];
    } else {
        return Bundle.EMPTY;
    }
}
```