# AccountManager and signature check

Tags: android, ipc, accountmanager

[Security tips](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html#Crypto) chapter related to `AccountManager` mentions that:

> If credentials are used only by applications that you create, you can
>   verify the application that accesses the AccountManager using
>   checkSignature().

Where in the code should I check the signature? I've already tried to use `Binder.getCallingUid(`) to obtain the UID of the calling process inside my own implementation of the `AbstractAccountAuthenticator`, but it returns 1000 as the system process performs IPC. I need to obtain UID/package name of the other app that tries to access the account created by my app as I want to perform the `checkSignature` check before returning the auth token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it's fairly simple. The package name, uid and pid of the real caller is contained in the `Bundle` passed as a parameter. This code should reside in the implementation of an `AbstractAccountAuthenticator`.

```
public Bundle getAuthToken(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account,
                           String authTokenType, Bundle bundle) {
    try {
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        String callerPackageName = bundle.getString("androidPackageName");
        // Caller app must be signed with the same key to get the auth token
        int signatureResult = packageManager.checkSignatures(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID,
                callerPackageName);
        if (signatureResult >= PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH) {
            return [bundle with the auth token];
        } else {
            return Bundle.EMPTY;
        }
}
```